# ajax result success null

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to figure out why my successful ajax alert is returning null from my controller.

I'm simply serializing a form, submitting that to the controller and parsing it in order to get an array breakdown.

The ajax is successful because the alert is triggered but the data, which should be the resulting array, is actually null in the alert.

What am I doing wrong?

view.blade

```
<form id="codeGeneration">
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach($getRuleAttributes as $attributes)
@if($attributes->title == 'New')
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['checked']"></td>
        <td><label>{{ $attributes->title }}</label></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attributet_id']" value="{{ $attributes->attributet_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_data']" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_type']" value="promo_codes">
    </tr>
@else
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['checked']"></td>
        <td><label>{{ $attributes->title }}</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_data']"></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attributet_id']" value="{{ $attributes->attributet_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="attribute[{{$i}}]['attribute_type']" value="promo_codes">
    </tr>
@endif
<?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
</form>

//ajax
var form_data = $("#codeGeneration").serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'savePromoInfo',
       data:{form_data:form_data},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
    });
```

controller

```
public function savePromoInfo()
{
    $form_data = $request->form_data;
    parse_str($form_data, $my_array_of_vars);
    $attr = $my_array_of_vars['attribute'];

    return json_encode($attr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it really successful? Can you try as a first line to return 'Ok'; for example to ensure that that's passing.

I notice also that you send the token out of the data in the ajax, but that should be part of the `data` object.

```
data:{form_data:form_data, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
```

Comment: Yes if I just put ok in the success then it returns correctly

Comment: and what is the response if you just use `return $attr;`?

Comment: it's no longer null but there's just nothing there, an empty alert basically

Comment: try dumping the result in the console instead of an alert, maybe that's not parsing the object correctly. So use `console.log(data)` in the success callback.

Comment: ok the console shows that it's getting the response but it's empty as well. But if I hit the button multiple times it shows each button call in the console

Comment: Then you need to debug the code on the server side my friend, because the AJAX seems to not be the problem, but your parser is.

Comment: Thank you, actually totally my fault. I just added 'Request $request' to my function params and it worked!